# Перенос компонентов на новою позицию внутри LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

Скорее все похожий вопрос задавали но я не нашел((

Есть `LinearLayout` в нем расположены несколько `TextView` значение может меняться и они не всегда помещаются по ширине экрана, как мне можно перенести на новую строку, если компонент не помещается по ширине экрана?

Comment: [FlexboxLayout](https://habr.com/company/speakasap/blog/300908/)

Comment: @pavlofff, думаю, коммент как ответ подошёл бы

Comment: @dev.android стандартным `LinearLayout` вряд ли получится, так как это слой горизонтали либо вертикали и переноса при переполнении текста не должно произойти, `layout orientation= horizontal` в `vertical` сам не перейдёт

Comment: @pavlofff, Спасибо очень помогли))